# How to convert RDD to DSteam in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, ignite

How can I convert a RDD to a DSteam?

In particular, I want to save a `DStream` in *Apache Ignite* and restore it in new batch. Is there any API in *Apache Ignite* to work with `DStreams` like `IgniteRDD`?

I don't want to use `InputDStream` to restore RDD, because input `DStreams` will read before previous stages finish.

Comment: You're reading from Apache Ignite? Or are you reading from a different source and want to save to ignite?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have an RDD that will update in stages. i am going to store it at end of the stages and read from ignite and join with newRDD at first of the stages.

Comment: Any reason why you're manually mutating an RDD instead of using stateful streams like `mapWithState`?

Comment: `mapWithState` does not have unique state if we use it multiple times in our driver.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique state"?

Comment: To convert an `RDD` to a `DStream`, you can use `ConstantInputDStream<T>`. But I'm not sure that will solve your question.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Dear Yuval, i call ‍`updateStateByKey‍‍` ‍or `mapWithState` twice in the driver. but first call is another state rather than second call.

Comment: @majidhajibaba Can you please provide more high level description of your use case? What are trying to achieve? Are you trying to read data from Ignite as a stream?

Comment: @Valentin in nutshell, I want to have a DStream that can update into micro-batches and inter micro-batches.  the RDD can save and restore to ignite, but DStream can not. if i save RDD in last line of driver and restore it into DStream in first line i will have an updatable DStream. but i can not convert RDD to DStream or vice versa.